# "ssl_protocols" directive is not allowed here - How to make conditional

Tags: nginx, ssl, lua

I have a number of servers in nginx that are using my configuration file, however I need to be able to add an if or a variable to change

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
```

to

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1;
```

is this possible?

I have tried an if statement but get

```
"ssl_protocols" directive is not allowed here
```

Comment: You might be able to accomplish this using nginx `map` feature.

Comment: What condition?

Comment: You have to understand that almost anything you would want to check (path, cookie, user agent) is not available at the moment when nginx have to choose protocol.